# Why is my tensorflow.keras highlighted even though i have keras packages installed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

[Snapshot of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdqHu.png)

I am trying to use imagedatagenerator for my assignment. I have also installed every packages needed but keras still highlighted saying cannot find reference 'keras' in **init**.py

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please let us know which `TensorFlow` version you are using and what are the steps you followed to install `TensorFlow` along with the platform environment details for better understanding to fix this issue.